# EXTJS tabpanel.items.items[0] undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm pretty much new to extjs stuff.

I have a problem with getting **textarea** in my **tabpanel**. **Tabpanel.items** is defined and has two objects in **items[]**.

But when I try get it directly to **tabpanel.items.items[0]** it is undefined. I tried finding this items by **ComponentQuery** and by using down with those itemId's. If needed I can update some code. Any ideas?

Edit: I don't get it. In firebug in DOM i see that tabpanel.items has lenght equals 2 when i do console.log(tabpanel.items.length) i get 0.

I run this pice of code:

```
var items = formPanel.getComponent('tabpanel-dialoglang').items;
console.log('tabpanel: ',formPanel.getComponent('tabpanel-dialoglang'));
console.log('tabpanel.items: ',items);
console.log('tabpanel.items.length',items.length);
console.log('tabpanel.items.items:', items.items);
console.log('tabpanel.items.items[0]', formPanel.getComponent('tabpanel-dialoglang').items.items[0]);
```

and get in console:

```
tabpanel: Object { xtype="tabpanel", name="tabpanel-dialoglang", itemId="tabpanel-dialoglang", ...}  
tabpanel.items: Object { allowFunctions=false, initialConfig={...}, items=[0], ...}  
tabpanel.items.length 0  
tabpanel.items.items: []  
tabpanel.items.items[0] undefined
```

but when i go to DOM of tabpanel.items it has two objects with I'm interested in.

Edit2: creating tabpanel:

```
'new-dialog': {
                afterrender: function(panel) {
                    var storeb = Ext.create('RBT.store.language.LanguageStore');
                    storeb.load({
                        params:{},
                        callback: function(records){
                            storeb.each(function (rec) {
                                var pp;
                                pp = {xtype: 'dialog-lang', title: rec.raw.lcid,itemId:rec.raw.lcid, id:rec.raw.id};
                                panel.down('#tabpanel-dialoglang').add(pp);  
                                panel.down('#tabpanel-dialoglang').setActiveTab(panel.down('#tabpanel-dialoglang').child('dialog-lang'));
                            }); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
```

**The problem was i tried to get items before it was fully renderd** I get timeout for one sec before geting the info and it work as I want.

Comment: `length` misspelt in console snippet

Comment: my bad, i misspel it here

Comment: can you add some more code? Like how you build the tabbed panel?